# Async Attempt WPF Blocking

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm learning about async/await keywords. I can't see what I'm doing wrote here syntactically?

I have the following two methods:

```
private async Task<string> PopupAsync()
{
  String result;
  using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\temp\JBM_SchedulingModule.xap"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Opened file.");
    txtData.Text = "Opened file.";
    result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

  }
  return result;
}
```

and

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  txtData.Text = await PopupAsync();
}
```

The main UI thread is freezing when I press the button and I don't want it to. Trying to understand why and how to fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's all your code? From what I can see, it looks like it should work (aside from the fact that you're reading a binary file as text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen is right. I figured it out. It does work as it's supposed to it. The reason why it was blocking was not because of ReadToEndAsync(), but the time it took to populate + load a 4MB string (from a file) to a WPF control.